# Converting python to c#

Tags: c#, python, helper

Python code:

```
    arr = list(input().split(' '))

    print("no" if len([x for x in arr if arr.count(x) > 1]) else "yes")
```

I did this one C# but it keeps looping with yes and no.

```
    String word = Console.ReadLine();
    int count;

    word = word.ToLower();

    String[] words = word.Split(' ');

    for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        count = 1;
        for(int j = i+1; j < words.Length; j++)
        {
            if(count > 1 && words[i] != "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no");
            }else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("yes");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the *original problem*, please?

Comment: What does this code do? Search for duplicates? `word.ToLower().Split(' ').GroupBy(x=>x).Any(g=>g.Count()>1)` will return true if there are any words appear more than once. It does this by grouping the words, then counting the items for each group.

Comment: What exactly is the goal? We can see that the Python code does indeed print only once while the C# code prints multiple times because it is in a loop.

Comment: The output is "yes" if no word is repeated, and "no" if one or more words repeat. It's searching for duplicate words in inserted string. @DmitryBychenko

Comment: You really should be comparing the result of `len` to something in the python code instead of relying on the 0 as false.  In any case you can just do `Console.WriteLine(words.Length == words.Distinc().Count() ? "yes" : "no")`

Comment: You can use `GroupBy()` then. Although a far faster solution would be to add the words into a HashSet<string>, checking if a duplicate already exists. This way you'll finish in a single iteration. This would make the python code run faster too

Comment: of course it loops, your python isn't a loop and the C# is.

Comment: @SomeStudent Python loops too, twice. Once due to `for`, once due to `arr.count(x)` for N^2 complexity

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check for duplicates, you can try a simple *Linq* (we put `"yes"` if all strings are `Distinct`, `"no"` otherwise):

```
using System.Linq;

...

String word = Console.ReadLine();

String[] words = word.Split(' ');

Console.WriteLine(words.Distinct().Count() == words.Length ? "yes" : "no");
```

No *Linq* solution:

```
String word = Console.ReadLine();

bool hasDuplicates = false;

HashSet<string> unique = new HashSet<string>();

foreach(string w in word.Split(' '))
  if (!unique.Add(w)) {
    hasDuplicates = true;

    break;
  }

Console.WriteLine(!hasDuplicates ? "yes" : "no");
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way to solve the problem, but this is the closest to the Python code you currently have.

```
String[] words = word.Split(' ');

Console.WriteLine(words.Any(w => words.Count(w2 => w == w2) > 1) ? "no" : "yes");
```

Or I guess this would be even more of a exact translation

```
Console.WriteLine(words.Count(w => words.Count(w2 => w == w2) > 1) > 0 ? "no" : "yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct code

```
    String word = Console.ReadLine();     
    String[] words = word.ToLower().Split(' ');
    var result = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        if(words.Count(x=> x == words[i]) > 1)
            result = false; 
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result?"yes":"no");
```

Comment: Nope, the python is only printing once.

Comment: You could exit the `for` loop early from the `if`

Comment: @juharr i know, but i want to be the more didactic I can, since OP clearly is a newbie. A good solution is the one based on hash set someone posted here